# Linux Small Text only version

Tags: linux, text, debian, customization

I need a small linux Text only version bootable installed on a partition of my hardrive, How can I customize a Linux version like redhat, debian, puppy etc. Please suggest some suitable distribution?

Comment: what size do you define small?

Comment: Off topic here; I'd suggest asking on unix.stackexchange.com or unbuntu.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you call small and what the purpuse of the installation is. I'd recommend [Debian stable][1] (Lenny) or [Ubuntu-server][2] for server-purposes. A really small distro is [Damn Small Linux][3]. If you just want to play around with a small-as-possible distro, you can try the time-consuming [Linux-from-Scratch][4].

Comment: damm small linux is what he is after. check PenDriver for more details on usb Linux.

Comment: The functionality I required is all hardware of my system working, some commands like wget, dd, ssh, grub boot loader.

Comment: I have used Linux Debian custom install from http://instalinux.com, Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

Archlinux, definitely. But it's not programming related.

Comment: arch linux is not what he is looking for. he needs a simple solution, not dig 3 days to compile solution.

Comment: O'ho. Actually I'm on arch. And maybe you are wrong. Do you think it's Gentoo? Or LFS?